# Using different variables for different threads in JMeter

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, jmeter

I am trying to do some performance testing on  a REST service.I am using JMeter to do that.

As many REST services, my request service requires authorization token to be passed in Authorization header.

I want to have 5 threads which should use five different tokens to mimic five users.

I have a single Thread group with five threads. I've added HTTP Header Manager to add Authorization header.

How can I substitute each users auth token for each thread? If I use variable then threads uses same auth token.

Is there any better approach for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given you have variables like:

```
token_1=sometoken
token_2=someothertoken
etc.
```

You can use [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) functions combination so each thread could use different variable holding the token as follows:

```
${__V(token_${__threadNum})}
```

Demo:

[image: Functions - threadnum + V]

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) articles series for more information on above and other JMeter functions

Answer (score 1):

> Within Thread Groups, the User Parameters Pre-Processor can be used to
>   set different parameters for each simulated user.

[Here are tips how to do it](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterFAQ#How_do_I_parameterize_my_JMeter_test_cases.3F)

Answer (score 0):

It is too late but I am suggested to use "User Parameters" in "Pre Processors" or "CSV Data Set Config" for inputting different variable.

User parameters allow to use martix to handle variable
[image: User parameters allow to use martix to handle variable]

CSV Data Set Config allow to read variable from local csv file
[image: CSV Data Set Config allow to read variable from local csv file]